# Setting div elements in front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code.

What I would like to have happen is when an item is checked a new div is created at the top of the page.

The new div contains an image set larger that the other images.

My ccs code:

```
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }

img {
margin: 10px 5px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Dynamically created code from js:

```
<div style="height:20px;z-index: 2"><img src="' + itemimg + '.jpg" /></div>
```

Div element with the other images.

```
<div style="width:960px;z-index: 1">
```

I have already tried:

Changing the img css `position` property from `absolute` to `relative`

Set the `z-index` on the second div to -1

I am trying to make the dynamically created div containing the image to stay in front of all other images.

Attempt at JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0f5u620u/

Test link

http://thenerdservice.com/dining/index.php

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
function reply_click(element)
{
    itemname = element.getAttribute("title");
    itemimg = element.getAttribute("alt");
    new_training();
}

// function to add set of elements
var tr = 0;
function new_training() {
    document.getElementById("training").style="";
    tr++;
    var newDiv = $('#training div:first').clone();
    newDiv.attr('id', tr);
    var delLink = '<input type="hidden" name="itemimg[]" value="' + itemimg + '"><input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' + itemname + '"> ' + itemname + '<select name=priority[]> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> </select> <a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deltr(' + tr + ')" > Delete ' + itemname + ' <div style="height:20px;z-index: 5"><img src="' + itemimg + '.jpg" /></div>  </a>';
    newDiv.find('tr:first th').text('Item ' + tr);
    newDiv.append(delLink);
    $('#training').append(newDiv);
    newDiv.find('input:text').val('');
}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function deltr(eleId) {
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('training');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
}
</script>

<style>
    a>div { display: none; }
    a:hover>div { display: block; }

    img {
        margin: 10px 5px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn-info {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #49afcd;
  *background-color: #2f96b4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#2f96b4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #2f96b4 #2f96b4 #1f6377;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5bc0de', endColorstr='#ff2f96b4', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>
    <br>Please select any items below to add to your wish list.
    <br>Also be sure to set your priority on each 1 = I really want it, 2 = I would like it, 3 = If its still left around ill take it.
</div>

<form name="myForm" method="post" action="addtraining.php" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dining Room</legend>
            <div id="training">
                <div id="tr">
                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save and Continue" class="btn btn-info">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div style="width:960px;z-index:1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img1" alt="DSC00501"  title="Antique Iron  " onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self"><img src="DSC00501.jpg" width="200"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img3" alt="DSC00541"  title="Butter Dish 1 " onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self"><img src="DSC00541.jpg" width="200"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img4" alt="DSC00546"  title="Flower Arranger and Silver Bow  " onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self"><img src="DSC00546.jpg" width="200"></a>
        <div>
            <img src="DSC00779.jpg" width="500"><br>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Candels" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Candels</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Left Plate" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Left Plate</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Right Plate" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Right Plate</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Tea Pot" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Tea Pot</a><br>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Left Mug" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Left Mug</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Right Mug" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Right Mug</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Bell" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Bell</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" id="imgc3" alt="DSC00779"  title="Salt and Pepper Shaker" onClick="reply_click(this)" style="outline:none;" target="_self">Salt and Pepper Shaker</a><br>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code? What you describe seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yssjao90/

Comment: I cannot really understand from the question but have you tried placing a higher z-index on the new image?  The higher the index the more "up-front" the picture will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image div position:absolute instead of the image inside of it:

```
a>div {
   position:absolute;
   margin: 10px 5px;
   display: none;
}
a:hover>div {
   display: block;
}
```

Making it absolute takes it out of the flow of page content, so it can be above everything else.